# GNUCASH: My chart of accounts is upside down at the top level

Tags: gnucash, chart, accounts

Gnucash: My chart of accounts is upside down (only at the top level) and badly sorted throughout.  For instance:

- Imbalance-USD
- Trading
- Orphan-USD
- Liabilities
- Expenses
- Income
- Equity
- Assets

Notice that the three accounts at the top are usually at the bottom.  Then the five top-level accounts are in REVERSE alphabetical order.

This was not always this way. Yesterday, it was right-side up.  **How can I get it back to right side up?**

On another note, is anybody else bothered that the top level accounts aren't sorted:

- Assets
- Liabilities
- Equity
- Income
- Expense

like every other accounting system in the world?
Thanks,
Ed

Comment: I am not familiar with gnucash. However, is there a column heading like "account name"? Try clicking on it.

Comment: Gnucash doesn't offer that. I've searched pretty hard, hence my question.

Comment: Have you checked you account codes, see: https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v4/C/gnucash-help/chart-create.html

Answer (score 0):

When in the accounts page (menu bar → View → New Accounts Page) you can sort accounts by clicking on the respective column header label.
(Click again to reverse the order based on the already selected sorting criterion.)

In reports, on the other hand, accounts are sorted by their respective *account code*.
You can edit these by right-clicking on the account name in the accounts page and selecting *Edit account*.
Sorting of account codes (at the *same depth* in the hierarchy) is based on dictionary order.

I have assigned the accounts of my account hierarchy account codes in line with the customary account sorting as mentioned by you, and usually use *account code* as the sorting criterion.
You can display/hide columns in the accounts page by clicking on the south-arrow () on the far right of the column header (you may need to scroll *horizontally* to see it).